# Which reader, writer, processor should I use for restartable multithreaded spring batch?

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

I want to create multi threaded step in my restartable job. As I saw many of Spring Batch readers are not thread-safe.
I have some questions related with that;

1. Is there any readers/writer/processor that can i use for restartable multi threaded step ?
2. If not, how can I do this without adding processors or status column to table ? Because our all tables are stable and can not be change for this.

I'm doing some researches but I want to ask here also.

Comment: please show what you have tried with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Restartability is not possible with a multi-threaded step, because threads can (and will) override each others state in the execution context. That's why the javadoc of stateful readers mentions to disable state management in multi-threaded steps. Here is an excerpt from the [JdbcPagingItemReader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.java#L66-L69):

```
The implementation is thread-safe in between calls to open(ExecutionContext),
but remember to use saveState=false if used in a multi-threaded client
(no restart available)
```

Same mention in the Javadoc of [JpaPagingItemReader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.java#L74-L77) and others. The [process indicator pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#process-indicator) is the way to go, but you said you can't add the column in your table..

What you can probably try is create a temporary table with the required data + column (in a first step) and remove it (in a final step) once the job is successfully executed. The lifecycle of the temporary table will be the same as the job instance (ie it can survive a job execution failure and be available for the next run). The successful job execution would remove it (this can be done automatically in a final step of the job to avoid manual house-keeping of temporary tables in your db).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Creating table is also retstricted by administration :( 
I m now searching about remote partitioning.